# How to configure / assign server resources (RAM, CPU) among the SharePoint applications in my farm

Tags: 2010, administration, architecture

How can i assign a specific resources percentage to a specific SharePoint applications in my farm, what i want is to assign:

X RAM + X CPU to application A

and

Y RAM + Y CPU to application B, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this directly in SharePoint, however you may be able to configure IIS or you could use a load balancer to achieve this.

IIS: - If you set each Web Application to use it's own app pool then you could use the app pool advanced settings to set the processor affinity or limit the max percent of cpu usage. You can also specify a max memory however this causes the app pool to recycle whenever the limit is reached and will cause performance issues if it happens frequently as the app pool will have to warm up the next time someone visits the site. I would not recommend setting the memory limit unless the app pool is behaving badly, even then it should be a temporary solution until the cause of problem is tracked down and fixed. As SharePoint is designed to be a scalable solution I would strongly recommend that you research the implications of changing app pool settings in this way.

Load Balancer: - If you configure several web front ends with the spec you require for each application then use the load balancer to direct traffic for each application URL to the appropriate web front end. This would obviously require 1 WFE per application so this may not be feasible if you have a large number of applications. You could also use DNS settings to achieve this however with the load balancer you could redirect traffic if a WFE goes offline.

As I final note I would point out that a farm should not need this sort of configuration if the capacity planning was done and was spec'd accordingly.

Comment: actually we have F5 appliance as a load balancer, i will check with this team about this  . thank you